# Dangerous wind from Grib file

Tags: grib

I need to filter out the low speed winds from the values inside a Grib file. This is my first time using this kind of data. I can read the file, and iterate inside all the GeoSpatialValues (getting lat, long and value from these).

To get the maximum resolution, should I use any specific list of the so called "component of wind" ?

Is there an easy way to calculate the speed from these values or should I iterate in the U values and then V values of wind to finally combine them into a vector?

Answer (score 1):

- **NOAA**

  If you are getting your data from the NOAA's Global Forecasting
  System (GFS), there's a GRIB message called `GUST` which is the
  surface wind gust expressed in m/s, but does not provide a computed
  speed `U . V . cos(Θ)` . You'll have to grep :GUST: in the GFS .idx
  file. [File download location for GFS.](http://www.ftp.ncep.noaa.gov/data/nccf/com/gfs/prod/)

  The WAVE model, though incomplete, provides `WIND`, which is the
  computed wind speed [File Download Location for WAVE model.](http://www.ftp.ncep.noaa.gov/data/nccf/com/wave/prod/)
- **ECMWF**

  ECMWF also provides a computed speed GRIB, named `WS` through their
  "essential dataset". They don't use inventory file like NOAA so
  you'll have to [download the grid directly from their ftp](ftp://wmo:essential@dissemination.ecmwf.int/).